# What are these parts!

Tags: engine

I have a generator with a briggs and stratton engine which kept dying on me. While trying to find out why, my neighbor helped me disassemble the carburetor. Finally, a week later a part arrived and I am trying to put everything back together. I tried my best to pay attention to what he did, but alas, I am only human and cannot recall where two parts came from. I even went and asked him and he cannot recall either.

[image]
[image]

I went through the [parts manual](http://bsintek.basco.com/BriggsDocumentDisplay/18qsCDXDnfBhU7y.pdf) and am 99% sure that one of the items (I believe the left one) is the shield-heat (#725) and one might be (kinda looks like) a piston assembly (#25), but super seriously doubt it as we did not mess with the pistons at all.

Both items have the same outside diameter, but one of them has a much wider inside diameter. One of them must connect two different fuel lines (assuming the one on the left which I assume is the shield-heat).

Can anyone identify these mystery pieces?

Comment: The one on the right looks like a spacer that goes between the air cleaner and the engine.  Do you have a long bolt?

Comment: @Edwin, you are a genius! You were exactly right. Could you please make that av answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on the right looks like a spacer that goes between the air cleaner and the engine. A long bolt goes through the spacer.